# Spring mvc 3+ display image in jsp which is from C drive

Tags: spring

on desktop one small image banner1.jpg 
using Spring mvc, i want to get and  display image on jsp page
how to display it.

Comment: Add some more content pls

Comment: How is Spring-MVC (therefore it is a Web application, typical hosted on a Server), related to to the Desktop and Drive C. -- Sorry but I afraid that you are missing a minimal understanding of how web applications work.